# Remove first 4 whitespaces from line

Tags: awk, sed, whitespace

I inherited a script I want to refactor.
for some reason the script is intended with four whitespaces.
I would like to remove leading four whitespaces from each line.
Is there any handy and fast way to do it?

```
    Message "Try to get Package Lock..."
    if waitForPackageLock("300","false")
        comment "UCS: Extra check if package lock is available."
    endif
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a difficult one.

```
sed 's/^   //'
```

Comment: Can't agree more!

Comment: managed to reduce the complexity:  sed 's/^ \{4\}\(.*\)$/\1/'

Answer (score 0):

Or edit your script with an editor.

```
vim file
:%<
```

`:` execute a command
`%` apply to all lines
`<` remove one indent

Comment: You forgot t save and quit.